# Do Visual Studio Community editions support Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)? Add-in designer doesn't show up

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vsto, office-interop, visual-studio-2017

I had **Visual Studio 2015 Community** and installed **Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015**.

I selected **File** -> **New** -> **Project**.

From the **New Project** dialog, I selected **Templates** -> **Office/Sharepoint** -> **VSTO Add-ins** -> **Word 2010 Add-in** because I have Microsoft Word 2010 installed on my laptop and I would like to create an add-in to target it.

[image]

Clicking the **Ok** button opened up **ThisAddin.cs** in the editor.

[image]

I could even bring Visual Studio to show me the **ThisAddin.Designer.xml** and **ThisAddin.Designer.cs** files.

[image]

However, I could not open the add-in in the designer mode. Not only was there no designer, there was no sight of the **Designer** menu item either in the **View** menu on the toolbar nor in the context-menu when I right-clicked **ThisAddin.cs**. Also, the **Toolbox** did not display any items for me to use.

[image]

The same thing happened after I installed Visual Studio 2017 Community and selected Office Tools to be installed during the installation process.

That makes me wonder if I am doing something wrong or if the Community editions do not support VSTO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes community edition supports VSTO. If you want the designer you should add a ribbon to your project. Right click project in the solution explorer --> add a new item --> VSTO --> Ribbon.

There is no designer by default since your are not forced to use it.